# My Check For A Raw reaction add wait for isnt working

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

i want to wait for a reaction but when i use a normal reaction add wait for, the message gets out of the message cache and it doesnt work anymore, i tried making a check with only payload as the param and i think i did it wrong

ive tried the code below and the check aswell, msg is the var of the message sent

```py
payload = await bot.wait_for("raw_reaction_add", check=paycheck)
```

Check:

```
    def paycheck(payload):
        return payload.message_id == msg.id
```

waits for any emoji on a certain message and then i check `if` its a certain emoji and if it is i do something etc

Comment: Try adding some logging to your `paycheck` function.  Make sure that it's actually being called and that the attributes of `payload` are what you expect.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I  Think Its Not The Event Problem, Maybe The Criteria Isnt Being Reached and nothings returning, im not sure how to do checks with raw reaction

Answer (score 0):

You did a mistake there-
In check-

```
def paycheck(payload):
    return payload.message_id == msg.id
```

> You put an _ there instead of . at message_id.

It should be like this-

```
def paycheck(payload):
    return payload.message.id == msg.id
```